# TensorFlow for Mobile Poets x86_64 compilation failed

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, tensorflow, error-handling

I am following Pete Warden's TensorFlow for Mobile Poets guide and seem to have a found an error. When I run "tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh" after about 20 minutes it returns an error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make: *** [/Users/ryan/Desktop/tensorflow-
master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/bin/ios_X86_64/benchmark] Error 1
+ '[' 2 -ne 0 ']'
+ echo 'x86_64 compilation failed.'
x86_64 compilation failed.
+ exit 1
```

I am running this on:
(MacOS High Sierra 10.13.2)
(Python 3.6.3)
(TensorFlow latest pull from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/ios)

Full Error Script:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JovTMGBJKbqzRPBzXy3cIQ-hbz76n0ab/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Can you attach a complete output from this script?

Comment: I have uploaded a link since the script took about 20 minutes due to it being large build @iga

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the debug log, the relevant error is:

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/ryan/Downloads/tensorflow2/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf_ios/lib/libprotobuf.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/ryan/Downloads/tensorflow2/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf_ios/lib/libprotobuf.a (1 slices)

This seems like a bug, since I would expect that file to contain code for all architectures, including x86_64.

Can you try running `lipo -info /Users/ryan/Downloads/tensorflow2/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf_ios/lib/libprotobuf.a` just to confirm that? Then can you file a bug at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues, since this seems to be an error on our side.

[Update, I think I've now fixed this with https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/16559 ]

Comment: After entering that line of code it returned: "Architectures in the fat file: /Users/ryan/Downloads/tensorflow2/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf_ios/lib/libprotobuf.a are: i386"